FFPEG: Errors opening audio input stream on MacOs
I am encountering the following warning (from Audio Toolbox?) very often when opening an external microphone audio stream with ffmpeg's libavformat on macOS:
CMIO_Unit_Converter_Audio.cpp:590:RebuildAudioConverter AudioConverterSetProperty(dbca) failed (1886547824)
This warning results on the codec id of the stream not being properly detected and it defaulting to the dummy AV_CODEC_ID_FIRST_AUDIO, which defaults to AV_CODEC_ID_PCM_S16LE, and results on distorted audio decoding the packet when this is not the correct codec.
You can observe the error with the following code, where I open and close and input audio stream 10 times in a row. Except for the internal macbook microphone, all the other ones I tried error more times than succeed, some only succeeding on the first call. From what I can tell, all these microphones correct detected codec with this code is AV_CODEC_ID_PCM_F32LE.
#include "libavdevice/avdevice.h"
#include "libavformat/avformat.h"
#include <stdio.h>

const char inputDevice[] = ":0";

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  const AVInputFormat *inputFormat;
  AVStream *inputStream = NULL;
  AVFormatContext *inputFormatContext = NULL;
  int ret;
  int i, j;

  // Initialize the input
  avdevice_register_all();

  inputFormat = av_find_input_format("avfoundation");

  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    ret = avformat_open_input(&inputFormatContext, inputDevice, inputFormat,
                              NULL);
    if (ret != 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open input audio device");
      break;
    }

    ret = avformat_find_stream_info(inputFormatContext, NULL);
    if (ret < 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't find stream information.");
      break;
    }

    for (j = 0; j < inputFormatContext->nb_streams; j++) {
      if (inputFormatContext->streams[j]->codecpar->codec_type ==
          AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO) {
        inputStream = inputFormatContext->streams[j];
        break;
      }
    }
    if (!inputStream) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't find a audio stream.");
      break;
    }
    printf("codecID: %s\n",
           inputStream->codecpar->codec_id == AV_CODEC_ID_FIRST_AUDIO
               ? "Incorrect"
               : "Correct");
    avformat_close_input(&inputFormatContext);
  }
  return 0;
}

Example output:
codecID: Correct
codecID: Incorrect
codecID: Incorrect
codecID: Incorrect
codecID: Incorrect
codecID: Correct
codecID: Incorrect
codecID: Incorrect
codecID: Incorrect
codecID: Correct

How can avoid the warning? What am I doing wrong?
